How to Push a Built APK from One Repository to Another Using Fastlane and GitHub Actions?
I have an Android project in one GitHub repository and I want to build the APK and then push it to another GitHub repository using Fastlane and GitHub Actions. Here is what I have so far:
lane :push_apk_to_repo do
  gradle(tasks: "assembleProductionDebug")

  repo_token = ENV['REPO_SCOPE_PAT']
  repo_url = "github.com/dummyuser/target-repo.git"
  apk_path = "/home/runner/work/source-repo/source-repo/app/build/outputs/apk/production/release/app-production-release.apk"
  target_repo_path = "apps"

  sh (
    set -e
    echo "Cloning the target repository..."
    git clone https://#{repo_token}@#{repo_url} target-repo || { echo 'Git clone failed'; exit 1; }

    echo "Copying the APK to the target repository..."
    cp #{apk_path} #{target_repo}

    echo "Changing directory to target-repo..."
    cd target-repo

    echo "Configuring Git user..."
    git config --global user.name 'dummyuser'
    git config --global user.email 'dummyuser@example.com'

    echo "Adding and committing the APK..."
    git add #{target_repo_path}/app-production-release.apk 
    git commit -m 'Upload apk'

    echo "Pushing to the repository..."
    git push origin main
  )
end

When I run this setup on GitHub Actions, I get the following error:
Could not find action, lane or variable 'target_repo'. Check out the documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions

Seems like something is not right with target_repo
